# Connection reset by peer error using cygwin on windows to connect minix via ssh

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, cygwin, openssh

i'm using minix on my virtualbox, I was able to connect to minix using putty yesterday, but today everything seems to fail. After this failing I tried to uninstall all the openssh and its etc/ssh directory and reinstall, tried other network adapters, tried using cygwin, and using pscp. But I simply can't connect to minix anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm now using this command on cygwin:

```
$ ssh -p 3022 -v -v -v root@localhost
```

and the output is:

```
OpenSSH_6.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 3022.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 3022: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 3022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Cem/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Cem/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Cem/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Cem/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Cem/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Cem/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.3
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to allow connections within your own subnet in the Cygwin `/etc/hosts.allow`.  Add a line like this to your `/etc/hosts.allow` on the Cygwin machine:

```
ALL : 192.168.123.0/24 : allow
```

and in your case, you'll need to add the `localhost` like so:

```
ALL : localhost 127.0.0.1/32 [::1]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.1]/128 : allow
```

The last line should have come with a stock Cygwin installation so it would be strange if you had to add it.

It matters where you enter it.  You will have some `DENY` entries and you should put it above those, but it should work if you put it with all of the other `ALLOW` statements.